How to get table name from dbms_tf.table_t in table macro
How would we go about getting the table name as a varchar2 when using table macros?
Oracle 19c database
Example table macro, where we would like to get the table name of the variable 't':
CREATE FUNCTION take (n NUMBER, t DBMS_TF.TABLE_T) 
                      RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO IS
BEGIN
   -- TODO do something with the table name
   -- if (t.name = 'foo') then
   RETURN 'SELECT * FROM t FETCH FIRST take.n ROWS ONLY';
END;
/

The table_t definition does not include the name of the table:
TYPE TABLE_T IS RECORD(
  column                TABLE_COLUMNS_T,
  schema_name           DBMS_id,
  package_name          DBMS_id,
  ptf_name              DBMS_id);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gettablename (t DBMS_TF.table_t) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO
IS
BEGIN
   RETURN 'SELECT '''|| t.table_name || ''' as table_name FROM DUAL';
END;
/

The doc is lying: there is a "table_name" field in the record:
TYPE TABLE_T          IS RECORD
(
  column                TABLE_COLUMNS_T,-- Column information, TABLE_COLUMNS_T is a TABLE OF COLUMN_T
  schema_name           dbms_quoted_id, -- the schema name OF ptf
  package_name          dbms_quoted_id, -- the package name OF ptf
  ptf_name              dbms_quoted_id, -- the ptf name invoked
  table_schema_name     dbms_quoted_id, -- schema name table
  table_name            dbms_quoted_id  -- table name
);


Unfortunately table_name does not exist in our database version (19c).
Maybe they added it in a newer version?
I'll mark it as an answer, if it indeed is in a newer version of Oracle DB.

Probably from 21c, in 23 for sure.

@Stsje - it's there in 23ai and 21c, but not 18c or 19c (run locally - has the same four attributes). The documentation doesn't seem to have been updated.

Thanks for the update. I'll mark it as answered anyway.
